# Is this box in my code editable?

Tags: php, html, popup

I have this `HTML` code. This code will make a box leak on my website and it's function is to validate the message sent by the user. Anw you can run the code [HERE](http://jsbin.com/ABoyaDiG/1/edit?html,output) to understand what I am talking about.

My question is how to edit the box and make it appear in the middle of the screen, above the current webpage? I mean like  POPUP WINDOW. It will open with `PHP` echo and tell the user that his message has been sent successfully.
So how to make it popup in the middle of the screen when the user submits his message?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things to do:
1. Your dropbox position is defined in js, modify here

```
var dropboxleft=screen.width/2
var dropboxtop=screen.height/2
```

2. Add negative margin to #dropinboxv2cover
    margin-left:-250px;
    margin-top:-150;
3. Change your current width of #dropinboxv2cover, it's too wide, change it to 500px.

Comment: THANK YOU veeeeeeeeeeeery much Godinall :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make the background black transparent and introduce this code in php echo? Thanks again.

Comment: What background did you mean? Whole page or just the popup window? And what do you mean by introduce this code in php echo? Add a button that will drop in the window on click? If that is the case, just add a button and include the onclick event as 'onClick="initboxv2();return false"'

Comment: On another note, your js code works but not validated, also your HTML markups, not validated too. You may want to improve that.